# Issue using to_date giving ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to pull together two fields to create a mm/dd/yyyy date field using case-when, and it keeps giving me error ORA-01722: invalid number.

```
case when 
  extract(month from t.date) >= t.month 
  then to_date(t.month || '/' || '01' || '/' || extract(year from t.date), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
  else to_date(t.month || '/' || '01' || '/' || extract(year from t.date)-1, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
  end as effective_date
```

Comment: ORA-01722: invalid number, month holds values 1-12

Comment: I also tried to use `to_char(t.month,'MM')` instead of just `t.month` and that gave ORA-01481: invalid number format model

Comment: Seems you data is string and you try to extract month in `extract(month from t.date)` so you need to do a different approach

Comment: I have a different case when argument where I am comparing the `extract(month from t.date)` against `t.month` and it does not have any error with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Oracle applies the concatenation operators **before** it does the arithmetic. So the ELSE branch of your CASE statement:

```
to_date(t.month || '/' || '01' || '/' || extract(year from t.date)-1, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

is going to execute something like `'02/01/2019' - 1`. Trying to subtract one from a string (crucially at this point it's a string not a date) not unreasonably results in an ORA-01722.

What you need to do is wrap the extract year in something to force the minus operation before concatenation. This will do it:

```
to_date(t.month || '/' || '01' || '/' || to_char(extract(year from t.date)-1), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: That works, thanks! I did not know that the concatenation comes before arithmetic operations, I will remember that now going forward!

Comment: Yeah, it's not an obvious one. I discovered it by trial and error, although I suspect it is documented somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First off the solution provided by @APC is necessary and sufficient for the issue presented by OP.  
However there is an alternative, esp. since I deplore string manipulation for dates. Convert a string to a date and from then on do ALL further processing with date functions(or timestamp as needed). There is NO reason to convert a date to a string except for final display or export. So I offer the following alternative for later viewers.  
The problem presented breaks down to the following:  
 Given a date and a target month  
 - if the month of the date is the same of later than target month return the first of the target month.  
 - if the month of the date is the prior to target month return the first of the target month in the prior year.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
with t as (select to_date('02/11/20','mm/dd/rr') src_dte, 1 tgt_mon from dual union all
           select to_date('2020-02-11'),                  2         from dual union all
           select to_date('11-Feb-2020','dd-mon-yyyy'),   3         from dual
         )
select t.src_dte, tgt_mon
     , case when extract(month from t.src_dte) >= t.tgt_mon 
            then add_months(trunc(t.src_dte, 'year'), t.tgt_mon-1)
            else add_months(trunc(t.src_dte, 'year'), t.tgt_mon-1-12)
       end as effective_date
 from t;
```

How it works.  
***All date functions return a valid date.***  
 1. trunc(src_date),'year') returns the date 01-Jan-*year*  
 
 2. From the above getting to the desired month is just adding the necessary number of months (0-11).Since the goal is tgt_mon subtracting 1 and then adding to the trunc result gives the *1-tgt_mon-year*.  
 3. For the prior year take the same result from above and subtract 1 year (12 months). There is no function subtract months so just add a -12. That gives *1-tgt_mon-year-1*.

I believe this is a superior method than string manipulation for date handling, but that's just my opinion. Take if for what you will.